# Best practices for implementing levels in cocos2d games

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, levels

I'm making a simple cocos2d adventure game, but have no clue how to implement any sort of levels. I've searched for tutorials, but can't find any.

Is there anything I can use to figure out levels in cocos2D?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned not being about to find any tutorials. I agree that finding free online tutorials for cocos2d can be challenging. I ran into the same problem when I started learning it. I recommend grabbing a book on cocos2d such as [Learning cocos2d](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321735625). There is so much to the API that you will have a very hard time creating even a rudimentary game without any tutorials or guidance, unless you have a lot of prior programming experience.

Comment: Thank you, I've actually got the book a nice while back and found the GameManager section. It's pretty confusing but I now have somewhere to start. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are so many ways to implement levels in a cocos2d game. I think a straightforward way is to:

1. Modeling your levels first. Decide what should be stored in a level's data model. I think typically you will have at least two kinds of data:

   - Player data (Run-time generated, e.g. score, character's current location, etc.)
   - Level data (e.g. what's on the screen in this level, the rule to pass this level, etc.) This data could be either fixed or dynamic. If the levels are designed by developer, like Angry Birds, you can store this part of data in external configuration files and load them on demand; if the levels are dynamically generated according to some rules, then the rules should be stored in the data model.)
2. Design a general game-play layer which can be initialized according to an instance of the data model above. The layer class controls the presentation of the level, and is responsible for user input handling.
3. If your levels shares some global data, you can make another shared data model to manage these things (e.g. total score, achievements, player's name, etc.). Create a shared instance of this class and manage the data in it via your game-play layer.

You could also consider more advanced way like using scripts (such as Lua) to implement the levels.